# SSI is not showing in browser

Tags: php, ssi

I made navigation and footer as a separate include file and includes them to all pages.i have SSI enabled in xampp and includes works even in live view in Dreamweaver , but browser is not rendering ssi and includes are not shown in browser. the code for include i am using is:

```
<?php include('./includes/navmenu.inc.php'); ?>
```

and path starts in the current folder so i placed ./
I am including this on all .php pages.

Comment: It may be the path issue - check once for the include path.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information about your code and configuration. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and see if you can provide an example of code that shows the problem. Also, make sure that the tags you select reflect the question: you've currently included a PHP tag, but make no mention of PHP in your question.

Comment: @prava i have checked the path and includes files are shown attached to the pages i include them to.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for your advise i tried to edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: What kind of page have you used this include in? Is the browser interpreting it as PHP?

Comment: yes i have used include in php page

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but when I incorporated SSI in PHP in my site I had to include an .htaccess file in the relevant directory. This is what mine reads:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html
```